# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:0

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

Given the following code

```java
  package parkinglottest;


    public class ParkingLotTest {


        public static void main(String[] args) {
            ParkingLot p=new ParkingLot(15);
            System.out.println(p.getMax());
            Car c1=new Car(1);
            Car c2=new Car(2);
            p.addCar(c1);//at parkinglottest.ParkingLotTest.main(ParkingLotTest.java:14) 
            p.addCar(c2);
        }

    }


        package parkinglottest;


        public class ParkingLot {
            private int max;
            public ParkingLot(int max)
            {
                this.max=max;
            }

            private Car[] cars=new Car[max];//if instead of "max" i put any other positive integer, it works just fine.
            int nr=0;
            public void addCar(Car c)
            {
                cars[nr++]=c; //at parkinglottest.ParkingLot.addCar(ParkingLot.java:17)
            }
            public int getMax(){
               return max;
            }
}
```

i get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Just because your initialization follows the constructor in the code doesn't mean that's the order of execution.

Comment: Just check in logcat and post what is  the error

Comment: I do not understand why do I get outOfBoundsException when declaring the array like this : private Car[] cars=new Car[max];

Comment: But if I declare it like this :private Car[] cars=new Car[10]; the whole programs works fine

Comment: Duh!!  max is zero.  Your assignment to the cars element is occurring in the initializer code that runs before the constructor.  Move that initialization into the constructor.

Comment: `max` is zero when the `new` operator is executed. Your assignment to the cars element is occurring in the initializer code that runs before the constructor. Move that initialization into the constructor.

Answer (score 3):

As ZouZou mentioned, you must initialize your car array in the constructor, because the `max` parameter is only available in that scope.

**Edit for clarification:** field variables are created and initialized before the call to the constructor. So when you initialized the cars array outside the constructor you initialized it with the value of the field variable `max` which is initialized to 0 (because int can't be null).

```
package parkinglottest;


public class ParkingLot {
    private int max;
    public ParkingLot(int max)
    {
        this.max=max;
        this.cars=new Car[max];
    }

    private Car[] cars;
    int nr=0;

    public void addCar(Car c)
    {
        cars[nr++]=c; //at parkinglottest.ParkingLot.addCar(ParkingLot.java:17)
    }

    public int getMax()
    {
        return max;
    }
```

Comment: The explanation is incorrect. If max wasn't available, he would get a compilation error. max is available, but it has its default field value: 0.

Answer (score 1):

max is not intialized and is 0, then the constructor is called, but the array has been already initilized

Answer (score 1):

```
public class ParkingLot {
  private int max;
  ...
  private Car[] cars=new Car[max];
```

Keep in mind the order of execution of initialization code:

1. all the instance initializers run (including initializer blocks), in the order of appearance in the source;
2. the constructor runs.

`max` is equal to `0` at the point you are using it to create the `cars` array.

Move the initialization of `cars` into the constructor, and watch out to use either the constructor parameter, or the instance variable *after* initialization.

Answer (score 1):

You have put your array initialization outside the constructor, so before the max was set.

```
public class ParkingLot {
   private int max;
   private int nr;
   private Car[] cars; // it was like saying = new Car[0], because max was 0.

   public ParkingLot(int max)
   {
      this.max = max;
      this.cars = new Car[max];
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you respected the usual conventions, you would write your class like this:

```
public class ParkingLot {
    private int max;
    private Car[] cars = new Car[max];//if instead of "max" i put any other positive integer, it works just fine.
    int nr = 0;

    public ParkingLot(int max) {
        this.max = max;
    }

    public void addCar(Car c) {
        cars[nr++] = c; 

    public int getMax() {
        return max;
    }
}
```

And it would become more obvious that at the moment the `cars` array is initialized, the constructor body hasn't been run yet, so max has the default value: 0. You need to initialize the array inside the constructor, after `max` has been initialized:

```
public class ParkingLot {
    private int max;
    private Car[] cars;
    int nr = 0;

    public ParkingLot(int max) {
        this.max = max;
        this.cars = new Car[max];
    }

    public void addCar(Car c) {
        cars[nr++] = c;
    }

    public int getMax() {
        return max;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Max has not been initialised to anything when the array is constructed. So it throws the exception becauss max is not a viable length to create on the array, it has no value.

Initialise the array in the constructor and it should work.

The order of your program is:
1: initialise the constructor to a length of max (happening outside the constructor
2: initialise max

Initialise the array in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

This can be a bit of a puzzle until you figure out the Java initialization scheme.

Statements outside of any method (that aren't simple declarations) are considered to be static (if preceded by the `static` keyword) or instance (if no `static`) *initializers*.  As such, they are collected into two unnamed methods (one for `static`, one not).  The `static` initializer method is executed when the class is loaded.  The instance initializer method is executed before any constructor is called.

In your case you want to leave `private Car[] cars;` where it is, but move `cars=new Car[max];` into the constructor.

To avoid this puzzle, novices are probably well-advised to avoid using such initializers, especially ones that depend on other values.